# Salesforce CTI save log after call

Tags: cti

In the Salesforce CTI API, how does one get the WhoID parameter when saving a log back to Salesforce after a call has completed?

This is the example code:

```
sforce.interaction.saveLog('Task',‘WhoID=0039000000HVnvh&CallDisposition=Internal&CallObject=TestCall&Description=Test task comments&Subject=Test Call&Priority=Normal&Status=NotStarted', saveLogCallback);
```

But where does the WhoID come from?  As only the phone number gets passed to the CTI application during click-to-call?

Comment: You can resolve the contact from the number. The contact can be used as the who id for the same

Comment: thanks, but how do I resolve the contact from the number?  Do I look it up through some API call?

Comment: WhoId is record Id for that customer, basically it will create a task for under that record Id. If you have record Id of customer then pass it, else create new record for that customer and pass.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest for you to consider 3rd party CTIs for this, like Tenfold for example. One of its main features is automatic call logging. You can use this [link](https://www.tenfold.com/tenfold-explainervideo) for more details.

Comment: Is this a company you work for? Please disclose your affiliation, if you have any.

Comment: Hey, Adrian. Yes, I work for Tenfold. I noticed that you've been tweaking my answers, may I know why? I hope to hear from you soon! Thanks.

Comment: Just trying to make the tone less conversational. This site is a terse question and answer format and we try to keep a high signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I appreciate your time explaining this. Have a great week! :)

Comment: You are linking this website all over SE. You are getting these posts flagged as spam. It's not acceptable to promote your service in posts.